# Records becomes repetitive in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have relational database. Each students has different history(one to many). The data is correct but the problem here is that student information become repetitive when loading in `datagridview`.I use `DISTINCT` function but it does not work. Can someone help me to figure out what's wrong with my code.

[image: Repetitive records]

vb.net code when load

```
Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspSELECTALL", cn)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 50
    dgv1.DataSource = dt
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgv1.Columns.Count - 1
        If TypeOf dgv1.Columns(i) Is DataGridViewImageColumn Then
            DirectCast(dgv1.Columns(i), DataGridViewImageColumn).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
        End If
    Next
End Using
```

stored procedure code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSELECTALL]


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  DISTINCT SI.StudentID,SI.Surname,SI.FirstName,SI.MiddleName, SI.StudAddress , 
            SI.BirthDay,SI.Gender, SI.Nationality, SI.BirthPlace,
            SI.TelNum,SI.SchoolWhereGraduated , 
            SI.DatesWhenGraduated, SI.SchoolLastAttended,
            SI.Note,SI.StudImage,
            PI.Father_FirstName,PI.Father_LastName,
            PI.Father_MI,PI.Father_Occupation, 
            PI.Father_TelNUm, PI.Mother_FirstName, PI.Mother_LastName,
            PI.Mother_MI,PI.Mother_Occupation,PI.Mother_TelNum,
            PI.Contact_FirstName,PI.Contact_LastName,PI.Contact_MI,
            PI.Contact_Mobile,PI.Contact_TelNum,PI.Contact_Address,
            SH.SchoolYear,SH.Levels,SH.Section,SH.DateEnrolled

            FROM StudentInformation SI 
            JOIN StudentHistory SH  
                ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
            JOIN ParentInformation PI
                ON PI.ParentID = SI.ParentID

END
```

Comment: Do you have multiple parentinformation rows? If you run this sql directly against the database, do you see duplicates?

Comment: When running to the sql server, the data is correct and shows this [SQL SERVER](http://img7.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/21908/219089777ff11ab8d09ed73b26b743149814bdf3.jpg) , But when i load it to a `datagridview`,it has a repetitive records . However, this issue happens only when one student has many history in studentHistory table

Comment: Does `dt` have the expected number of rows before you load it into the datagridview?

Comment: You mean, you want to output multiple different histories with only a single, non-repeating student id?

Comment: @Cyval Yes, that is what i want to do. I only want non repeating student id to diplay in the `GridView` when loading.

Comment: @Mort, what do you mean? How can i have the expected number of rows in the dt?

Answer (score 0):

If you want show in the `DataGridView` only distincts id's of students,
then you need use another query.
Your current query always return multiply rows per student if student have more then one history.
One approach will be removing all columns of table `StudentHistory` from `SELECT` statement and keep `DISTINCT`keyword in the query.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT SI.StudentID,SI.Surname,SI.FirstName,SI.MiddleName, SI.StudAddress , 
        SI.BirthDay,SI.Gender, SI.Nationality, SI.BirthPlace,
        SI.TelNum,SI.SchoolWhereGraduated , 
        SI.DatesWhenGraduated, SI.SchoolLastAttended,
        SI.Note,SI.StudImage,
        PI.Father_FirstName,PI.Father_LastName,
        PI.Father_MI,PI.Father_Occupation, 
        PI.Father_TelNUm, PI.Mother_FirstName, PI.Mother_LastName,
        PI.Mother_MI,PI.Mother_Occupation,PI.Mother_TelNum,
        PI.Contact_FirstName,PI.Contact_LastName,PI.Contact_MI,
        PI.Contact_Mobile,PI.Contact_TelNum,PI.Contact_Address

FROM StudentInformation SI 
        JOIN StudentHistory SH  
            ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
        JOIN ParentInformation PI
            ON PI.ParentID = SI.ParentID
```

Another way will be filter `DataTable` which was filled by your query.

```vb
Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspSELECTALL", cn)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 50
    'Filtering for distinct rows
    Dim view As New DataView(GetData())
    Dim distinctColumnNames As String() =
    {
        "StudentID", "Surname", "FirstName", "MiddleName",
        "StudAddress" ' and so on
    }
    Dim distinctValues As DataTable = view.ToTable(True, distinctColumnNames)       
    dgv1.DataSource = distinctValues 
    'Your other code
End Using
```

`view.ToTable(True, distinctColumnNames)` if first parameter is `True` then only distinct rows, based on columnnames will be included

Comment: thanks for commenting. Can you show me some sample code just to begin with. Im just a beginner in developing vb and kinda confuse.

Comment: Thanks for your big help